# Add tags to HTML automatically

Tags: html, parsing, dom, beautifulsoup

I have a folder full of .html files. I wish to edit all of these files. I wish to edit them as below. Here is my original code :

```
<td class="class1" align="left" valign="top" height="100%" width="100%">Text to edit</td>
```

I wish to replace all occurrences with:

```
<td class="class1" align="left" valign="top" height="100%" width="100%"><h2>Text to edit</h2></td>
```

Notice the added h2 tags.

What's the best and easiest program/method I can use to apply these rules to an entire folder in Windows 7? BeautifulSoup? Is there a easy way to do this? What programs/APIs would you recommend for similar work?

Thanks.

Comment: shell scripting. you use mac(or unix based) or windows?

Comment: @JonnieJS Windows 7 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather do it using regular expressions.

Just write an script in your favourite scripting language that opens sequentally all those files and use something like PHP **preg_replace** method.

XPath is also an option as recommended by Jerome but I believe that it is kind of "overkill" for such a simple need.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider html as xml you can accomplish this with the use of xpath.